# Rails: How do I access attributes of associated records in nested form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model `availability` that has a collection of `days`.

Each `day` has a `name`.

`availability` accepts nested attributes for `days`:

```rb
class AvailabilitiesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_login

  def new
    @availability = current_user.create_availability

    Date::DAYNAMES.each do |day_name|
      @availability.days << Day.new(name: day_name)
    end
  end
end
```

This form shows the name of each day in a text input:

```
<%= form_with model: @availability, local: true, url: { action: "create" } do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :days, @day do |day_form| %>
    <%= day_form.text_field :name %>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

I don't want a text field, I just want to display the day name. Something like:

```
<%= form_with model: @availability, local: true, url: { action: "create" } do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :days, @day do |day_form| %>
    <h2><%= @day.name %></h2>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

The above example does not work as the value of `@day` is nil. How do I access the name of each day?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to pass the second argument to `fields_for`:

```
<%= form_with model: @availability, local: true, url: { action: "create" } do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :days do |day_form| %>
    <h2><%= day_form.object.name %></h2>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

This will call the `days` method on the object wrapped by the form builder (@availability). Passing the second argument is only ever needed if you want to overide this behavior.

Depending on what inputs you want you might not even need to use fields_for in the first place though. If you just want let the users select the days of the week you could just use [the collect helpers](https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html). Fields for is only really relevant if you want to create separate inputs for the nested record such as the hours per day.

Comment: I intend to create separate inputs for the nested record. At the moment, I still do not know how to reference the name attribute of each record.

Comment: `day_form.object` will give you the object wrapped by the form builder.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to display all the `days` which belongs to given `@availability`.

The `object` method returns the object wrapped by the form builder.

In your code

```
form.object #=> will return the availability object.

day_form.object #=> will return the day object.
```

Once you get the object then you can access the model methods and attributes.

Try this.

```
<%= form_with model: @availability, local: true, url: { action: "create" } do |form| %>
  <%= form.fields_for :days do |day_form| %>
    <h2><%= day_form.object.name %></h2>
  <% end %>
  <%= form.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Hope this works for you!

Comment: You need to remove `, @day` as you're passing nil.

Comment: @max - thanks for pointing this out, edited the answer.